# Jquery li click event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I've been using JQuery and I tried my code on JFiddle and it worked fine but when I do it on my site it doesn't work at all, basically I need a event to be sent when a list item in my userlist is clicked.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/r5pzakk4ikvck3t/style.css?dl=1">
        <script src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/2hdvqa4ma51m0pw/jquery-1.9.0.min.js?dl=1"></script>
        <title>Chat</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="userlist-container">
            <div id="userlist-title">User List</div><br />
        </div>

        <div id="main-container">
            <div id="messages">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="control-container">
            <input type="text" id="TxtMessage" placeholder="Message" onKeyPress="SendMsg(event)" style="text-align:center;" >
        </div>

        <div id="alert-container" hidden="hidden">
            <div id="alert-main">
                <span id="alert-content"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
$("#userlist-container > li").click(function(e) {
    alert("TEST");
    var username = "@" + this.html + " ";
    $("TxtMessage").value(username);
    $("TxtMessage").focus();
});
```

EDIT:

Once the page has loaded it connects to the server and adds `<li>lalala</li>` inside the `userlist-container`.

Comment: If you are just adding an `<li>` inside of the `#userlist-container` `div`, that's invalid HTML.  All `<li>` elements _must_ be inside a `<ul>` or `<ol>`.

Comment: Try $("#userlist-container > ul > li")... See http://jsfiddle.net/gdpsU/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your selector in the bind is wrong:

```
$("#userlist-container > li")
```

There is no `li` your HTML is:

```
<div id="userlist-container">
    <div id="userlist-title">User List</div><br />
</div>
```

Also you seem to be missing `#` for the id selector inside the event.

So your event should probably be similar to:

```
$("#userlist-container > div").click(function(e) {
    alert("TEST");
    var username = "@" + this.html + " ";
    $("#TxtMessage").value(username);
    $("#TxtMessage").focus();
});
```

**Edit**

> should have probably told you guys that once it does some wizzard
>   stuff, li's get added so there are actually li tags in there.

I added your code to a fiddle and no `li` tags seem to be added when inspecting the DOM.

The [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YKjmy/)

That could be just the fiddle though, not sure. I'm assuming if the `li` tags are injected that you need to use delegate binding using `on` if you are using jquery 1.7 or later or `delegate` if you are using 1.6 or earlier.

Similar to this:

```
// jQuery 1.7 or later
$("#userlist-container").on("click", ">li", function(){
    alert("TEST");
    var username = "@" + this.html + " ";
    $("#TxtMessage").value(username);
    $("#TxtMessage").focus();
});

// jQuery 1.4.3 to 1.6.x
$("#userlist-container").delegate(">li", "click", function(){
    alert("TEST");
    var username = "@" + this.html + " ";
    $("#TxtMessage").value(username);
    $("#TxtMessage").focus();
});
```

Comment: Crap, should have probably told you guys that once it does some wizzard stuff, li's get added so there are actually li tags in there.

Comment: Tried both these, neither of them fired the click event.

Comment: @user1763295: I added your code into a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YKjmy/) and inspecting the resulting DOM there are no `li` elements at all. `$("li").length` returns `0`. However, that could just be the way things work in the fiddle. Can you make sure that the `li` are injected. I copied the resulting DOM even into notepad++ and did a search of tags, there is no `li` tags anywhere.

Comment: it doesn't support websockets. The document loads, connects to a websocket which then sends it a userlist which is put inside li's. It looks like so when inserted:http://icap.me/i/n54ARoVELD.png

Comment: @user1763295: Ah, I see. Could you post the relevant resulting HTML please in your question so we can see the `li` tags. As mentioned, there might be an issue with the `li` being in a `ul` and you need to adjust your selector to either `$("#userlist-container ul>li")` or just `$("#userlist-container li")` or you get invalid HTML as `li` tags inside a `div` is invalid and maybe the browser is adjusting something to cope with the invalid HTML (some do that)

Comment: @user1763295: In your script `https://dl.dropbox.com/s/69ymb6dx88m8a1o/script.js` you are binding to the click event like this: `$("#userlist-container > ul > li").click(function(e) {...}` but you got no `ul` as per your picture, you only got a `#userlist-container > li` instead. Is changing your script to `$("#userlist-container > li").click(function(e) {` making a difference? Please note this is still invalid HTML though even if it starts working.

Comment: Managed to get this working using >ul>li and fixing my ul formatting. Thanks guys, you're all freaking great people.

Answer (score 1):

Your selectors are wrong, add the # prefix to indicate an id

```
$("#TxtMessage").value(username);
$("#TxtMessage").focus();
```

If your click event isn't even firing, make sure that you are attaching the event *after* the document is loaded

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    //code here  
});
```

Comment: Missed that, but the click event its self isn't firing at all is my issue.

Comment: That's because you have no `li` elements that are direct descendants of `#userlist-container`. See the answer given by @François Wahl

Comment: Ah so I should register the event after it adds all the li tags?

Comment: yes, otherwise it has no elements to attach itself with. Also look at the other answers as you do not seem to have `li` elements

Comment: Or use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to make a dynamic binding whenever the elements are added.